# Regular language derived by union and concatenation

Tags: regular-languages

How can I represente finite language using set notation?
G = {ab, bb}, which means G = ({a} ∪ {b}{b})
D = {ca, aa}, then D = ({c} ∪ {a}{a}).

How about {aaac, aacc, abac, abcc}?

Also, can I represent A = {ardor, ardour, glamor, glamour, labor, labour, neighbor, neighbour} as A = {ar, gla, la, neighb} ∪ {o{u}?r}?

Comment: Do you need to break each strings of the language into union and concatenation of singleton sets?

Comment: Did you intend  $G = \{ab, bb\}$, which means $G = (\{a\} ∪ \{b\})\{b\}$,   $D = \{ca, aa\}$, then $D = (\{c\} ∪ \{a\})\{a\}$?

Comment: For effective line breaks in "markdown" append two blanks to the preceding line.

Comment: (Carefully distinguish between concatenation and union.)